# passing int variables in C++ - error check not returning value

Tags: c++, variables

okay so I am trying to check variables when they are input by the user, however they don't seem to stick. now the error check seems to work, but the variable is lost somewhere leaving 'num = 0'

I had copied some of this code from another source but I am not sure where it is going wrong.

I would like to input a number, check if it is an integer, and then return said integer to the variable 'num'.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int checkCin(int var)       {//open function

bool ok = false;//set variable to false
while (!ok)/*if variable is false, loop*/               {//open loop 

    cin >> var;

    //this will cheack if anything is in variable other than an integer
    if(!cin.fail() && (cin.peek()==EOF || cin.peek()=='\n'))        {//open if
        ok = true;//this will end loop
        return var;
}//close if

    //this will clear the cin and ignor whats left - ignoring this part stops an infinate loop cycle 

    else        {//open else
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cout << "Error, enter a number" << std::endl;

    }//close else
}//close loop

//prepared for next input
ok = false;

}//close function

int main()    {

int num = 0;

checkCin(num);

cout << num << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to read up on [passing variables by reference and copy](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1232/c-pointers-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference/).

Comment: You're not assigning the return value of checkCin.  num is being assigned 0 and nothing else.  Did you mean to write 'num = checkCin(num)'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the read number from your function by doing

```
return var;
```

at some point, but you are not using the result in your main function. You just have

```
checkCin(num);
```

in there, which throws away the result. Also, the input argument does not really make sense, because you pass by value and therefore cannot modify the value seen in `main` inside the function. What you could do is declare `checkCin` without parameters and assign the return value in `main`, i.e.

```
num = checkCin();
```

This would be most obvious for someone reading your program the first time, because `checkCin` doesn't need the original value of `var` and therefore it doesn't need to be passed in.

Another way would be to declare `checkCin` as taking a reference and returning nothing, i.e. `void checkCin(int& var)`. Then you could keep your code in main, because now the function can actually modify the variable `num` passed in from main. However, this second solution would be quite uncommon for a function that returns only a single simple piece of data like an `int`.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code (you also see, with proper indentation, the "open loop", "close loop", etc. comments would not be necessary, because nesting levels are obvious):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int checkCin() {//open function
    int var;
    while (true) { //open loop 
        cin >> var;
        //this will cheack if anything is in variable other than an integer
        if(!cin.fail() && (cin.peek()==EOF || cin.peek()=='\n')) {//open if
            return var;
        } else { //open else
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(256,'\n');
            cout << "Error, enter a number" << std::endl;
        } //close else
    } //close loop
} //close function

int main()    {
    int num = checkCin();
    cout << num << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: read number?

okay
    'num = checkCin(num);' works thanks guys

Comment: While that might work, it doesn't make sense. Why are you passing in `num` in the first place? It is not used by your function.

Comment: Also, your `ok` variable in the function is useless. The `return` statement quits the function and returns the value `var` as the result, so the loop will end automatically. Anything after return won't ever be executed, including the `ok = false;` statement at the end of the function. If control flow could get here, it would be an error anyways, since the function would end without a `return`.

Comment: That's lovely, thanks for the quick reply
I was passing the variable through so the function would have somewhere to return the value in 'var' too.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just declare an `int var;` locally in your function and return that. And, of course, you're welcome! :)

Comment: @Zachary Maybe this cleaned-up version of your code gives you some ideas.

Comment: that's exactly what I done, you made perfect sense don't worry. :)